# download a source video with python

Tags: python

I have tried To download this video but it says
"certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))"

Is there any way to download this video

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

url = "https://s317d2.akwam.link/download/1650615491/6261134384bc3/Pablo.S1.E1.720P.WEB-DL.AKWAM.mp4"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open("video.mp4", "wb") as handle:
    for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
        handle.write(data)
```